# PHP foreach if condition

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

This should be easy, but I can´t seem to get it to work. I have an multidimensional array and I wan´t iterate trough the array and check for a specific value. If the value equals a string then echo out a value of the array.

Here is the array and two values (the full array has a lot more):

```
$users = array( 
    "username01" => array("fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Online"),
    "username02" => array("fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Offline")
);
```

I wan't to `echo` out the Full name of each user that is "Online". Here is what I'm using today but it's not working:

```
$string = "Online";
foreach ($users as $username => $data) {
    $fullname = $data["fullname"];
    $status   = $data["status"];

    echo $status."= ";
    if ($status == $string) { 
        echo "Yes"; 
    } else { 
        echo "No"; 
    }
      echo "<br>";
}
```

If I echo out `$fullname` and `$status` the correct data is printed out. But for some reason the IF statement is not working. If the user is Offline the echo is "No", but if the user is Online there is no echo at all.

**EDIT - Solved**
Updated the array keys with quotes and $data[...] as was suggested below. I found a typo that was causing a false output. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: First, you can just use `$data["fullname"];` and `$data["status"];` and second, I get the expected output of "YesNo". http://codepad.org/rfO0N0r7

Comment: I can't reproduce. I'm getting the expected result (`YesNo`).

Comment: There is not problem in your code. It runs [fine](http://ideone.com/PJ9Xfg)

Comment: I'm also getting the correct output.

Comment: Though it is working , he forgot to enclose his array keys with single quote. So php will first try to locate a constant with that name , and when it failed most of the time it will treat it as a string. **but this is not a standard behavior** so this behavior is not fixed. And the way he used foreach also indicates his lack of knowledge about how it works.

Comment: I uptated the code to use $data[...] and also fixed the Array to include "" around the array keys. There is a change, now I always get [NoNo] like both users are offline. But if I print out the array I can see that one is online. I just can´t figure this out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working okay for me :

```
<?php 

    //you forgot to enclose your keys by Single Quote (')
    $users = array( 
    "username01" => array('fullname' => "Firstname Lastname",
                'status' => "Online"),
    "username02" => array('fullname' => "Firstname Lastname",
                'status' => "Offline")
);

    $string = "Online";
    foreach ($users as $username => $data) {
      //Notice this line
      //$username is the key 
      //at the first iteraiton it will be uername01
      //$data holds the array of username index in the array named $users
      $fullname = $data["fullname"];
      $status = $data['status'];
      if($status == $string) { echo "Yes"; } else { echo "No"; }
    }

?>
```

Go through [foreach in php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to know more details about foreach.

Hope that helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. I used this code and ran it on my server. First I got a false output but that was due to a typo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome , @SkuliAxelson :) . It's great to hear that my code helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has something to do with the missing quotes around "fullname" and "status" in the array definition. The code you printed is working, but it throws warnings.

Try it like so:

```
<?php
$users = array( 
    "username01" => array("fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Online"),
    "username02" => array("fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Offline")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed my array but now the reply is always [NoNo] like both users are offline when one is clearly online.

Answer (score 1):

odd - looks like it should work...

try this:

```
$users = array( 
    "username01" => array(  'fullname' => "Firstname Lastname",
                            'status' => "Online"),
    "username02" => array(  'fullname' => "Firstname Lastname",
                            'status' => "Offline")
     );

foreach ( $users as $user )
{
    if( strcasecmp( 'online', $user['status'] ) == 0 )
    {
        echo $user['fullname'] .': Online';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $user['fullname'] .': Offline';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your array.
Give this a try.

```
$users = array( 
    "username01" => array(  "fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Online"),
    "username02" => array(  "fullname" => "Firstname Lastname",
                            "status" => "Offline")
     );
```

You forgot `"` for `status` and `fullname`.
Works on my local XAMPP like it should.